# Populate Only When Conditions Are Met

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a mongodb database and   I use mongoose with nodejs.

I need return data from the next query populating "tabela_tuss" only if I have the field "temtussvinculado=true".

Here is what I am doing:

```
ConvProced.find({'convenioId':new ObjectId(req.params.id)})
        .populate('convenioId')
        .populate({
             path:'procedId',
             populate:{
                 path:'tabela_tuss',
                 match: { 'procedId.temtussvinculado': true}
            }
        })
        .exec( (err,data) => {
           callback(err,data,res)
        })
```

My problem is that my match with "procedId.temtussvinculado:true" has no effect and "tabela_tuss" is never populated.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my schemas:

```
////
var conveniosSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nome: {type: String, unique:true},
  ativo: {type: Boolean}
 });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Convenio', conveniosSchema,'convenios' );
////

////
const agProcedimentosSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ativo:{type:Boolean},
  temtussvinculado:{type:Boolean},
  tabela_tuss:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Tuss_22'}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Ag_procedimento', agProcedimentosSchema,'ag_procedimentos' );
///

////
const tuss_22Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  codigo: {type: String, unique:true},
  descricao:{type: String},
  tabela:{type: String}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Tuss_22', tuss_22Schema,'tuss_22' );
////

//../models/convenioprocedimento
var conveniosProcedsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   convenioId:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Convenio'},
   procedId:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Ag_procedimento'},
   valor_particular:{type:Number},
   valor_convenio:{type:Number},
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('ConvenioProcedimento', conveniosProcedsSchema,'conveniosprocedimentos' );

//my query:

const ConvProced = require('../models/convenioprocedimento');
ConvProced.find({'convenioId':new ObjectId(req.params.id)})
    .populate('convenioId')
    .populate({
         path:'procedId',
         populate:{
             path:'tabela_tuss',
             match: { 'procedId.temtussvinculado': true}
        }
    })
    .exec( (err,data) => {
       callback(err,data,res)
    })
```

Comment: The `match` arguments to `.populate()` are actually processed against the collection "before" any "join" is emulated, as how populate actually works. So instead this should be `.populate({ path: 'procedId', match: { 'temtussvinculado': true }, populate: { path: 'tabela_tuss' } })`

Comment: Thank  you, Mr Neil Lunn. It solves my problem

Comment: @Neil Lunn , sorry, my mistake. The problem continues. The path "procedId" allways must be populated. If I follow your tip, it wasn´t populated when  temtussvinculado<>true. I need "tabela_tuss" populated only when  temtussvinculado=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are actually asking here is to *"Only populate where a condition within the data says to do so"*, which is something that is not actually a "directly" supported action of [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) or usage of the "nested populate" syntax.

So if you want to impose "conditions" on which items are actually populated or not, then you must handle the populate calls "manually".

The basic premise in your case is that you would need to inspect the value which you need to get from the "initial" top level [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) call, but then "only" call the "inner" populate when the given condtions actually allow it.

So your code should then probably look like this using "Promises" using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) where you basically "loop" or [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each query result and test the `proceedid.temtussvinculado` to see if it is `true/false`, and where `true` we actually issue a [`Model.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) call, otherwise just return the data in it's present state:

```
ConvProced.find({'convenioId':new ObjectId(req.params.id)})
  .populate('convenioId procedId')
  .exec()
  .then(data =>
    Promise.all(
      data.map( d => 
        ( d.proceedid.temtussvinculado )
        ? mongoose.model('Tuss_22').populate(d,{ path: 'proceedId.tabela_tuss' })
        : d
      )
    )
  )
)
// Populated conditionally
.then( data =>
  // Do something with data
)
.catch(err => console.error(err)); // or something else with error
```

There are different options available other than 'Promises', but it is the no dependency option. Alternate cases such as [`async.map`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) to do much the same thing, but is an additional dependency if you do not already have it:

```
ConvProced.find({'convenioId':new ObjectId(req.params.id)})
  .populate('convenioId procedId')
  .exec((err,data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    async.map(data,(d,callback) =>
      ( d.proceedid.temtussvinculado )
        ? mongoose.model('Tuss_22').populate(d,{ path: 'proceedId.tabela_tuss' },callback)
        : callback(null,d)
      (err,data) => {
        if (err) throw err; // or something
        // Conditionally populated
      }
    )
  })
```

Also demonstrated with a full working example, which is actually a little more complicated than what you need to do, since the "condition" is nested within another array in this example:

```
const async = require('async'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');


const subInnerSchema = new Schema({
  label: String
});

const innerSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  populate: Boolean,
  subs: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Sub' }]
});

const outerSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  inners: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Inner' }]
});

const Sub = mongoose.model('Sub', subInnerSchema);
const Inner = mongoose.model('Inner', innerSchema);
const Outer = mongoose.model('Outer', outerSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
}

async.series(
  [
    // Clean data
    (callback) =>
      async.each(mongoose.models,(model,callback) =>
        model.remove({},callback),callback),

    // Insert some data
    (callback) =>
      async.waterfall(
        [
          (callback) =>
            Sub.create([1,2,3,4].map( label => ({ label })),callback),

          (subs,callback) =>
            Inner.create(
              [0,2].map(x => subs.slice(x,x+2))
              .map((el,i) => ({
                name: i+i,
                populate: i == 1,
                subs: el
              })),
              callback
            ),

          (inners,callback) =>
            Outer.create(
              inners.map((inner,i) => ({
                title: i+1,
                inners: [inner]
              })),
              callback
            ),

        ],
        callback
      ),

    // Conditional populate async.map version
    (callback) =>
      Outer.find().populate('inners').exec((err,outers) => {
        if (err) callback(err);

        async.map(
          outers,
          (outer,callback) =>
            async.map(
              outer.inners,
              (inner,callback) =>
                (inner.populate)
                  ? Inner.populate(inner,{ path: 'subs' },callback)
                  : callback(null,inner),

              (err,inners) => {
                if (err) callback(err);
                outer.inners = inners
                callback(null,outer);
              }
            ),

          (err,outers) => {
            if (err) callback(err);
            log(outers);
            callback();
          }
        );
      }),

    // Conditional populate Promise
    (callback) =>
      Outer.find().populate('inners').exec()
        .then(outers =>
          Promise.all(
            outers.map( outer =>
              new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                Promise.all(
                  outer.inners.map( inner =>
                    (inner.populate)
                      ? Inner.populate(inner,{ path: 'subs' })
                      : inner
                  )
                ).then(inners => {
                  outer.inners = inners;
                  resolve(outer)
                })
                .catch(reject)
              })
            )
          )
        )
        .then(outers => {
          log(outers);
          callback();
        })
        .catch(err => callback(err))


  ],
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Which produces the output showing the "conditional" selection, from using either approach of course:

```
Mongoose: subs.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: inners.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: outers.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: subs.insert({ label: '1', _id: ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b3"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: subs.insert({ label: '2', _id: ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b4"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: subs.insert({ label: '3', _id: ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b5"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: subs.insert({ label: '4', _id: ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b6"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: inners.insert({ name: '0', populate: false, _id: ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b7"), subs: [ ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b3"), ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b4") ], __v: 0 })
Mongoose: inners.insert({ name: '2', populate: true, _id: ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b8"), subs: [ ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b5"), ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b6") ], __v: 0 })
Mongoose: outers.insert({ title: '1', _id: ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b9"), inners: [ ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b7") ], __v: 0 })
Mongoose: outers.insert({ title: '2', _id: ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13ba"), inners: [ ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b8") ], __v: 0 })
Mongoose: outers.find({}, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: inners.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b7"), ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b8") ] } }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: subs.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b5"), ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b6") ] } }, { fields: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b9",
    "title": "1",
    "__v": 0,
    "inners": [
      {
        "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b7",
        "name": "0",
        "populate": false,
        "__v": 0,
        "subs": [
          "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b3",
          "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b4"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13ba",
    "title": "2",
    "__v": 0,
    "inners": [
      {
        "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b8",
        "name": "2",
        "populate": true,
        "__v": 0,
        "subs": [
          {
            "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b5",
            "label": "3",
            "__v": 0
          },
          {
            "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b6",
            "label": "4",
            "__v": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
Mongoose: outers.find({}, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: inners.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b7"), ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b8") ] } }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: subs.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b5"), ObjectId("5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b6") ] } }, { fields: {} })
[
  {
    "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b9",
    "title": "1",
    "__v": 0,
    "inners": [
      {
        "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b7",
        "name": "0",
        "populate": false,
        "__v": 0,
        "subs": [
          "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b3",
          "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b4"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13ba",
    "title": "2",
    "__v": 0,
    "inners": [
      {
        "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b8",
        "name": "2",
        "populate": true,
        "__v": 0,
        "subs": [
          {
            "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b5",
            "label": "3",
            "__v": 0
          },
          {
            "_id": "5961830256bf9e2d0fcf13b6",
            "label": "4",
            "__v": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So you can see there that in much the same way there is a "boolean" field which is being tested to determine whether to perform a `.populate()` or just return the plain data instead.